# How to use angular promise as part of a string

Tags: javascript, string, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm looking for a generic solution regarding handling promises and string creation. Basically a timing issue. This code isn't the actual code, but illustrates my problem and my attempted solutions.

I have a two json objects that I need to combine. Either one or both objects might have values that require some information from an API. This information is used to create a label showing which two objects have been combined.

Object with defined label (no lookup necessary):

```
var object1 = {
    type: "some.type",
    distribution: 50,
    label: "Male"
}
```

Object with dynamic label (and psuedo code to get label via service $http request):

```
var object2 = {
    type: "some.type",
    distribution: 50,
    value: "68"
}

// call service to get the data to populate the label
myService.getDynamicObjectData("68").then(function(response){
    // should be "Alaska"
    object2.label = response.data.label; 
});
```

Desired combination:

```
var combinedObj = {
    type: "some.type.combined",
    distribution: 25,
    // ideally label would be "Male > Alaska"
    label: object1.label + " > " + object2.label
    values: [object1, object2]
}
```

My problem is that object2.label is not populated until after the combination object has been created, specifically the label string. In the view, I'm seeing "male > undefined". I've managed to get as far as "male > 68" but that doesn't really help. When I'm not combining objects, the label is updated as soon as the promise is resolved and there is no issue getting "Alaska" and "Male" to show up as two unique entries. When I combine and create the string from the two labels, it's happening too fast.

The object1 and object2 are created in a service that deals with reading in data and creating these kinds of objects for internal use, then this combination code is in another service dealing with the nesting of such data; so I can't really use a watcher to update that value.

I've tried setting the label to the promise hoping that will work, but it doesn't:

```
var promise = myService.getDynamicObjectData("68").then(function(response){
    // should be "Alaska"
    object2.label = response.data.label; 
});

var object2 = {
    type: "some.type",
    distribution: 50,
    value: "68",
    label: promise
}
```

The label is just an object with {then(), catch(), finally()} inside. I can't figure a way to get the actual returned values, even if then() returns the right value.

I've tried to use an array and a filter so that I'm never really creating the string until the last while, which means that since the string isn't "real" then it should work as the model is finally updated (as it does when showing objects separately):

```
var combined = {
    type: "some.type.combined",
    distribution: 25,
    label: [object1.label, object2.label]
    values: [object1, object2]
}

module.filter('labelFilter', function(){
    return function(input){
        if(angular.isArray(input)){
            // but input[1].label is a promise object, how do I get the resolved value?
            return input[0].label + " > " + input[1].label 
        }
        return input;
    }
});
```

So, I'm turning to the community to see what I might be able to do here. How to you create a string where part of that string is based on the result of a promise? I think if I use $resource, I'd be able to set label: labelResource, and labelResource would eventually resolve to the actual data I want (even the parent object of the data I want would be helpful). Unfortunately, there is other logic that is too complex for $resource so I can't use it without a bit of a refactor. I'm hoping to be able to set label to something like $q.deferred.result and have it all work out (even if I still need the filter).

Anyway, thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with promises and $q

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q go to the bottom of page where you can find $q.all which basically is a solution to your problem, when all promises will be resolved you can then call you function to join the strings (labels)

Comment: Yeah, I've done that somewhere else in the app, but the problem here is the separation of services. The service that does the request for label is a separate service from the one that is doing the string concat. any suggestions for that?... EDIT, actually, think I might have an idea.

Comment: I don't see a problem here, if both services return promises: `Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.` so you do it by `$q.all(serviceOnePromise, serviceTwoPromise)`. I found a working fiddle that you can check for the solution http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasBurleson/QqKuk/

Comment: Maurycy, you magnificent bastard! that was the ticket! I did need to do a little more to get it working, but that was exactly what I needed. Because there are potentially many of these requests running nearly the same time, I've stored each promise in an object with its own name, then in $q.all(), I used that name to target the specific promises that that particular nest should wait for. Works like a charm! Cheers!! BTW, I recently put together an image from some of my photos of this past lunar eclipse and it looks like your avatar: https://www.flickr.com/photos/42311345@N04/13867063614/

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking out the method mentioned here to do it inside filters.

I made a simple fiddle demonstrating async filters which you can use as a starting point to this problem -> http://jsfiddle.net/7eqsc/5/

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {


})
      .filter('test', function ($q, $timeout) {
         var cache={};
       return function (input) {
        if (!cache[input]){
        //I used timeout, but anything that needs to happen async can happen here
        $timeout(function () {
            //do something with the input
            cache[input]=input+'!';
        }, 500);
            //return something in the meanwhile to hold it
            return 'loading';
        }
        else return cache[input];
    }
   });
```

Not tested of course, but try something like:

```
module.filter('labelFilter', function () {
var cache = {};
return function (input) {
    var cachedItem = cache[inputHash(input)];
    if (!cachedItem) {
        if (angular.isArray(input)) {
            input[0].label.then(function (text) {
                //once the promise is finished, put the correct verison inside the cache
                cache[inputHash(input)].label = text + " > " + input[1].label;
            })
            //meanwhile, return the unmodified object.
            return input;
        }
    } 
    return cachedItem;
}

//you'll have to identify each input for the cache somehow.. it can be a combination of fields for example
function inputHash(input) {
    return input.id; //some unique identifier..
}
```

});

Just keep in mind calling a promise "label" can be very confusing, you should try and reorganize your code so it's more clear when a prop has a promise inside.

Good luck!

Comment: this is nice too. I like the idea of the filter handling this since it is technically a display thing, but it's a bit more complicated to wrap my brain around than the other answer. Thanks for answering though!

Comment: Simple is always better! Cheers :)